# Calculating $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing

$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
I think it is supposed to be $-1$ but I can't figure it out. First I tried applying L'hospital but I quickly realized that you get the same fraction after applying it. Then I tried this.

$L = \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
$L = \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$
$L = \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$
$L = \frac{1}{1} = 1$
What am I missing?

Comment: When you factor $x^2$ out of the root, it becomes $|x|$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I didn't know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt {1+x^{2}}$ is not $x \sqrt {1+\frac  1 {x^{2}}}$ for $x <0$. It is  $-x \sqrt {1+\frac  1 {x^{2}}}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $x=-\dfrac1h\implies h\to0^+,h>0$

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{h^2+1}{h^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{h^2+1}}{\sqrt{h^2}}$$

Now $\sqrt{h^2}=|h|$ which is  $=+h$ as $h>0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{-|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=-1.$$